# how to change linphone ios background color white to another?

Tags: ios, user-interface, background-color, xcode9, linphone

I am trying to change the graphics view of linphone ios in xcode 9. I could able to change maximum changes(UI) except background color. The default background color of all page is white. Iwant to change it with other color. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change background color of te xib files `PhoneMainView.xib` and `UICompositeView.xib`.

It will change whole app background color.